# Ugly border around search box on Area 51 Discussion

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51, design

The Area 51 Discussion site has a square border around the search box which itself is rounded.  Looks a little amateurish to me.

[image]

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: @David: Firefox 3.6.3

Comment: Its OK in Firefox 3.6.7 on Win XP SP3. No themes installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I can post an image, and for no other reason:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzp2B.png

[image: status-no-repro]

Comment: Ah, so the rounded search box is what's different.  I think I have a user style that's doing that.  So I guess that square border is how it's supposed to look.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know that is about the new design on Area 51